# Dictionary-style conditional referencing between two dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, dictionary, conditional-statements

I have two data frames. DF1 is a list of homicides with a date and location attached to each row. DF2 consists of a set of shared locations mentioned in DF1.

DF2 contains a latitude and longitude for each unique location. I want to pull these out. NOTE: DF2 contains *shared* locations, which may correspond to multiple homicides in DF1, which means the two DFs are different lengths.

I want to create latitude and longitude vars in DF1 when a location in DF2 is equal to the location in DF1 (assuming location names are exact between the two DFs). How do I pull the latitude and longitude from DF2 for which the location in DF2 corresponds to a given homicide record in DF1?

Small reproducible example:

DF1: (dataframe of incidents)

```
| Incident  | Place  |
| --------  | -------|
| Incident 1| Place 1|
| Incident 2| Place 2|
| Incident 3| Place 2|
| Incident 4| Place 3|
| Incident 5| Place 1|
| Incident 6| Place 3|
| Incident 7| Place 2|
```

DF2: (dictionary-style lat-lon manual)

```
| Place  |Latitude |Longitude |
| -------| ------- | ---------|
| Place 1| A       | B        |
| Place 2| C       | D        |
| Place 3| E       | F        |
| Place 4| G       | H        |
```

DF3 (what I want)

```
| Incident | Latitude | Longitude |
| -------- | -------- | --------- |
|Incident 1| A        | B         |
|Incident 2| C        | D         |
|Incident 3| C        | D         |
|Incident 4| E        | F         |
|Incident 5| A        | B         |
|Incident 6| E        | F         |
|Incident 7| C        | D         |
```

I have tried:

```
DF1$latitude <- DF2$latitude[which(DF2$location == DF1$location), ]
```

It returned the following error:

```
Error in DF2$latitude[which(DF2$location == DF1$location), ] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions
In addition: Warning message:
In DF2$location == DF1$location :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

In response to a comment suggestion, I also tried:

```
DF2$latitude[which(DF2$location == DF1$location)]
```

However, I got the error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, latitude, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 1220
In addition: Warning message:
In DF1$location == DF2$location :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: `DF2$latitude[which(DF2$location == DF1$location), ] ` doesn't work whereas `DF2$latitude[which(DF2$location == DF1$location)] ` might get what you need. If not, maybe you want `DF2[which(DF2$location == DF1$location), ]`.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You can try `dplyr`'s left_join(). The code below keeps all the rows in `DF1` and add variables in `DF2` if it finds a match based on `location`.

```
library(dplyr)
DF3 <- left_join(DF1, DF2, by = "location")
```